# Alternatives to using LinearSolve

Tags: functions

```
mat = 
  Table[
    If[i == j, .5, If[i == j - 1 || i == j + 1, .25, 0]], {i, 1, 100}, {j, 1, 100}];
b = Table[1./i, {i, 1, 100}]; 
old = Table[1, {i, 1, 100}]; 
new = Table[1, {i, 1, 100}]; 
dim = 100;
actual = LinearSolve[mat, b];
```

I want to find different ways to get the actual value without using the `LinearSolve` command.

Comment: You could always use `Inverse` to compute the inverse of `mat`, but in most situations `LinearSolve` is preferable.

Comment: This is just a tridiagonal matrix with constant elements. Analytic solution is available. See here https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0305-4470/29/7/020/meta

Comment: You can use `actual = Inverse[mat].b` as Sjoerd Smit has commented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to find different ways to get the actual value without using
>   the LinearSolve command

You can use `Solve`

```
ClearAll[x,i,j];
mat = Table[If[i == j, .5, If[i == j - 1 || i == j + 1, .25, 0]], {i, 1, 100}, {j, 1, 100}];
b = Table[1./i, {i, 1, 100}];

vars = Table[x[i], {i, Length@b}];
eqs = Thread[mat.vars == b];
Solve[eqs, vars]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Compare to

```
actual=LinearSolve[mat,b]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]